# Execution of class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier failed

Tags: azure-ad-msal

I have setup an Azure AD application and I am trying to connect my application locally from eclipse and I get the below error.

```
[ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-1] ERROR com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.PublicClientApplication - [Correlation ID: c4035431-b9dc-486a-b48c-1bac2ae4306c] Execution of class com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier failed.
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.WSTrustResponse.parse(WSTrustResponse.java:74)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.WSTrustRequest.execute(WSTrustRequest.java:48)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.WSTrustRequest.execute(WSTrustRequest.java:89)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.getAuthorizationGrantIntegrated(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.java:126)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.java:40)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:59)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:17)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.exec(CompletableFuture.java:1582)
```

I have followed exact steps mentioned in - https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-desktop/tree/master/Integrated-Windows-Auth-Flow

Please find my source code below:

```
private final static String CLIENT_ID = "********-****-****-***-*******"; //Azure generated client id
private final static String AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/************/"; //Azure generated tenant id 
private final static Set<String> SCOPE = Collections.singleton("User.Read User.ReadBasic.All");
private final static String USER_NAME = "******@****.com.au"; //fully qualified user name who is trying to get the token

TokenCacheAspect tokenCacheAspect = new TokenCacheAspect("sample_cache.json");

PublicClientApplication pca = PublicClientApplication.builder(CLIENT_ID).authority(AUTHORITY)
                .setTokenCacheAccessAspect(tokenCacheAspect).build(); 



IAuthenticationResult result;
try {
     IntegratedWindowsAuthenticationParameters parameters = IntegratedWindowsAuthenticationParameters
                    .builder(SCOPE, USER_NAME).build();

            result = pca.acquireToken(parameters).join();
} catch (Exception ex) {


throw ex;
} return result;
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you ever managed to find out the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's not explained in these samples but here's what I found: out of the box Java cannot get a Kerberos ticket from Windows, this ticket is needed to authenticate with Azure. The error retuned by MSAL4J (a NullPointerException) it not helpful at all

**Solution 1**
When running Java >= 13 add the JVM option `-Dsun.security.jgss.native=true` this enables the (new) GSSAPI, more information [here](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6722928)

**Solution 2**
Change the registry value `\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Kerberos\Parameters\AllowTgtSessionKey` to 1, more information [here](https://info.michael-simons.eu/2012/07/23/java-7-jaas-and-kerberos-single-sign-on-vs-newer-windows-systems/)

**Solution 3**
Run `kinit` in a command prompt, this will cache a Kerberos ticket in `C:\Users\<user>\krb5cc_<user>` and Java should be able to use it

**Solution 4**
(Not tested) disable Credential Gard

Appart for solution 1, the security implications are not clear to me

Comment: I changed my jdk to "15.0.2" and added the JVM option suggested in "Solution 1", but I still get this error.  Could you please help: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-desktop/issues/15 ?

Comment: I see in your github issue that you're trying to authenticate a @microsoft.com account. I think SSO only works for Active Directory domain joined computers and accounts